# Is the 6MB limit of AsyncStorage because of SQLite?

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, expo, asyncstorage

Per [Known storage limits](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/limits) :

> Total storage size is capped at 6 MB by default. You can increase this size by specifying a new size using feature flag.

Is this a limit of SQLite on Android itself? Or a cap just for AsyncStorage? Does it apply if I use SQLite directly on Expo?

Comment: SQLite can go much higher than 6MB for storage.  I have no idea where they got that number from.  That's not an Android limitation, its something that library imposes.

Answer (score 0):

No you can set it higher.

See the docs you refer to.

Add:
AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=10

android/gradle.properties

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size